# Does truffle test mimic the exact network state of an actual migration?

Tags: truffle-test

I've defined a truffle migration step as follows:

Deploy my 'main' smart contract, nothing out of the ordinary:

```
 var UniversityVoting = artifacts.require('./UniversityVoting.sol');

   module.exports = async (deployer) => {

     await deployer.deploy(UniversityVoting);

};
```

I then deploy an `ERC20` token contract, called `VotingToken`. As you can see, in `module.exports`, I get an instance of `UniversityVoting` which I deployed in step 1, so I can then pass the address of the newly deployed `VotingToken` to it:

```
var VotingToken = artifacts.require('./VotingToken.sol');
var UniversityVoting = artifacts.require('./UniversityVoting.sol');

module.exports = async (deployer) => {

    UniversityVotingInstance = await UniversityVoting.deployed();

    await deployer.deploy(VotingToken, UniversityVotingInstance.address);

    await UniversityVotingInstance.setVotingTokenAddress(VotingToken.address);

};
```

This works fine using `truffle migrate`
and I can indeed see the correct `VotingToken` address in Ganache: [image]

But in a test written in JavaScript that I execute using `truffle test`, where I create a new instance of `UniversityVoting`and call a `getter` method that returns `deployedVotingToken` it returns a `0 address`. Why would that happen in a truffle test? I thought it was supposed to run your migration files?

```
describe("Deploy and use the child institution contract", function() {
  before(async function() {

    universityVoting = await UniversityVoting.new(
      {
      from: developerAccount
    });

...

// In an 'it' block

const originalToken = await universityVoting.getVotingTokenAddress();

originalToken.should.equal("[exampleAddress]");  // Here it says that AssertionError: expected '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' to equal '0x34344343434'
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an elementary mistake from my part. In a truffle test environment, if I have to create a new instance of any arbitrary contract, in this case `UniversityVoting`, why wouldn't I have to with `VotingToken`? Very silly. So I called a setter and gave the `deployedVotingToken` instance variable to `UniversityVoting` and it is no longer unitialised/0 address.

```
votingToken = await VotingToken.new(
  universityVoting.address,
  {
  from: developerAccount
});
const setToken = await universityVoting.setVotingTokenAddress(
  votingToken.address,
  { from: developerAccount }
);
```

Comment: Since you are deploying a separate instance the migrations scripts are not called on it. If you have used `UniversityVoting.deployed()` instead it will be initialized.

Comment: I wasn't going to comment because rules but this is a gamechanger, thanks. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it!